# Passing parameters from Python to powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, parameters

I am trying to pass parameters to a powershell script from Python, but powershell is only picking up the first part of the statement and ignoring everything after the space
Here is the code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe",
                      "C:/Users/fthoma15/Documents/testcase.ps1",
                      elem[2].replace('--','',1)], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

The `elem[2].replace('--','',1)` evaluates to an exec storecproc value, but when I run the code powershell just picks up the exec part and ignores the rest. Is there a way to escape the space in the variable?

Comment: On Windows you should enclose parameters with spaces in them with double quote characters (`"`). So for this use `'"{}"'.format(elem[2].replace('--','',1))`

Comment: Thanks for the response @Martineau But the parameters are a variable thats being picked from a text file., if i pass it as "elem[2].replace('--','',1)", will it not be picked up as a string?

Comment: `elem[2].replace('--','',1)` is a string, and `'"{}"'.format(elem[2].replace('--','',1))` is the same string enclosed within `"` characters.

Comment: WOW...That worked like a charm...! Newbie  here, Thank you very much @martineau

Comment: That's good to hear…you're welcome. `;¬)`